# I need to run a code when I save a Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have already code this in excel with Workbook_BeforSave and it works, but in Project I don´t know how to do it, because it doesn´t work the same way. I just need my code runs when I save the project

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim PtjR As Integer
    Dim PtjP As Integer
    Dim FechaRI As Date
    Dim FechaRF As Variant
    Dim FechaPI As Date
    Dim FechaPF As Date
    Dim ListaT As String
    Dim ListaTT As String
    Dim t As Task



    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If t.Text1 = "Subtarea" Then

            FechaPI = DateValue(t.Start)
            FechaPF = DateValue(t.Finish)
            PtjR = t.PercentComplete
            PtjP = Round((DateValue(Now) - FechaPI) / (FechaPF - FechaPI), 2) * 100
                If PtjP >= 100 Then
                    PtjP = 100
                ElseIf PtjP < 0 Then
                    PtjP = 0
                Else
                    PtjP = Round((DateValue(Now) - FechaPI) / (FechaPF - FechaPI), 2) * 100
                End If


            If PtjR < PtjP Then
                ListaT = ListaT & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "La tarea " & t.Name & " se encuentra en DELATE, lleva " & PtjR & "% y debería llevar" & " " & PtjP & "%."

                    If FechaPF - DateValue(Now) < 0 Then
                        ListaT = ListaT & ". Esta tarea debió terminar hace " & -(FechaPF - DateValue(Now)) & " días."
                    ElseIf FechaPF - DateValue(Now) <= 7 Then
                        ListaT = ListaT & ". Esta tarea termina en " & FechaPF - DateValue(Now) & " días."
                    End If


            End If

        Else
        End If

    Next t

    MsgBox ListaT, vbCritical, "Advertencia"
End Sub
```

Comment: If it is too complicated, it will work to me, if the code runs when I open the project, the file

Answer (score 0):

MS Project events work like they do in Excel. Try the Project [BeforeSave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.beforesave) event or Project [Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.open) event.

In the VB Editor, open the module for `ThisProject`, select `Project` from the left drop-down list at the top of the code window, then select the event you want to use from the right drop-down list. That will create the procedure for the event handler; add your code there.